# parsing JSON with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, stringify

I have a JSON response returning special characters in the response below.

```
[{"@networkName":"nameOfNetwork1"}, {"@networkName":"nameOfNetwork2"}]
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of the '@' symbol or a way around it? Or how I could get retrieve it so I can display the network name in my view?

Comment: That's perfectly valid JSON so it wouldn't get rid of the `@`. You could access it as is (`myObject["@networkName"]`) or replace it at some point (`myObject.networkName = myObject["@networkName"]`)

Answer (score 2):

There are various options you have how you can access the your JSON to display the values, which are to use `bracket [] notation` or add a new property to your JSON so you can use `dot . notation`.

Here are some simple ways of doing both. (To see the results of what is being output open your browser developer tools > console)

The first `console.log()` accesses the values using `bracket notation`.

The `for loop` adds a new key value pair into your JSON.

The second `console.log()` access the values using `dot . notation` to access the newly created value

```js
var obj = [
  {"@networkName":"nameOfNetwork1"}, 
  {"@networkName":"nameOfNetwork2"}
];

console.log(obj[0]["@networkName"]);
// This will log "nameOfNetwork1"

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  // To will add a new key value into your data with a key name of newName
  obj[i].networkName = obj[i]["@networkName"];
}

console.log(obj[0].networkName);
// This will log "nameOfNetwork1"
```

Comment: No problem, glad it could help.